# substitute for landsat 7 for land classification?

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, land-classification, landsat-7, geomatica

I am doing a project where I need to do a land classification for a forest reserve in Honduras. The dates I need are 2005, 2010, and 2015. I'm good for 2015 with LS8, but I am having difficulty with imagery for the other dates, especially 2005 because of the SLC-Off issue with LS7. I have done some mosaicing with some of the LS7 images to destripe it but it has still left some bad pixels. Because this area is outside of North America I cannot find LS5 data for 2005.I also face issues with cloud cover so finding enough quality images for a mosaic is a challenge.

Any suggestions or ideas on other satellites I could use or how to deal with the LS7 data? I have access to Arcmap, ENVI and geomatica.

Answer (score 2):

[SPOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOT_(satellite)) has similar characteristics and is often used as a substitute.

[ASTER](http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/) has similar characteristics and is often used as a substitute.

Both will have the required coverage dates. ASTER will not have the blue band.

Globcover has 2005 data but is at a poorer resolution. It has 2010 as well. MERIS, MODIS and other coarse systems are used to fill gaps in Landsat 7.

You should have no issue getting [Landsat 5](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) outside of the USA. It is freely available.
 I would use TM as the closest and best match to ETM+

If it did not need to be primary data then just use GFC (00, 05, 14) and it is likely processed to a higher level than a novice could do anyway, is all Landsat based, is at the 30m resolution, and frankly just rocks for tree cover.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the data composite available on the site [Global Forest Change](http://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.2.html) , but it is done on more than one year.

If you are lucky, you could also find some data on the SPOT image catalog, but it was not a systematic acquisition.

Finally, you can try some gap filling with coarse resolution images (MERIS or MODIS)

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, your site might be included within the SPOT World Heritage data set (CNES started reprocessing SPOT data acquired before 2010 and delivering them for free, but as the cost for CNES is high, new data sets are added very progressively)

https://theia.cnes.fr/rocket/#/search?collection=SpotWorldHeritage